# How to customize icon size in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I have change height of `ActionBar` with `<item name="android:height">80dp</item>`, however, then the icons in actionbar seem to be too small, and also the button represented by the icon only change the height(which is a square at first, but now is a rectangle).

How can I customize the icon size like `ImageView`? and change the button to be a square again?

Comment: The [Material Design metrics for the Action Bar / App Bar](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) state that 'For extended app bars, the height is equal to the default height plus content increment(s).' where content increments are the original height on the action bar - why are you changing it to `80dp`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake becasue we think `ActionBar` is a little bit small, we need to make it bigger.